# Динамическое изменение высоты строки

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Создал Custom Table View Cell: сверху название картинки, по середине сама картинка и снизу разные контролы. Как растягивать строку таблицы по середине, в зависимости от контента, т.к. с сервера получаю картинки с разными размерами?

Как определить высоту строки? Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут есть два варианта:

1. в heightForRowAtIndexPath вы просто складываете высоту "название картинки" + (высчитываете размер картинки из самого файла картинки, какая она есть) + высоту "снизу разные контролы".
2. вы задаете в кастом целке конкретный размер для имеджа и вписываете контент как Aspect Fit. ну и, естественно, сжимаете, если нужно, сам файл.

конечно второй будет правильней, потому что вам может прийти хз какой размер, например панорамная картинка в два гига.

Answer (score 1):

Не до конца понял что же собственно вам нужно.

Что значит "растягивать строку таблицы по середине", изменять ее высоту? Тогда нужно определить у делегата таблицы метод `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, метод будет дергаться при каждой перезагрузке данных, но он в принципе может заставить тормозить вашу прогу

Что значит "Как определить высоту строки", в чем тут конкретно затык? Ответ же очевиден - высота строки определяется как сумма высот всех входящих в нее компонентов + отступы. Главная проблема тут как не загрузить картинку два раза (в подсчете высоты и в выводе), но это за пределами данного вопроса и относится к тому как вы реализовали взаимодействие с сетрвером

Answer (score 0):

определить высоту сроки вы можете в помощью метода NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: - для iOS 7
или sizeWIthFont:constrainedToSIze:LineBreakMode: - для более ранних версий

например:

```
self.textRowHeight = [self.restaurant.welcomeMessage boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 42.0, 9999.9)
                                                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.descriptionFont}
                                                                      context:nil].size.height
```

изменять высоту ячеек вы можете методом UITableViewDelegate

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return calculatedValue;
}
```

в центровкой для начала поиграйте с autoresizingMask для всех subviews и самой UITableViewCell или, если вы используете autolayout, то это будет еще проще - просто выставляем нужные ограничения контенту. Еще может пригодиться свойство contentMode у UIImageView. Удачи

Comment: насколько я понял, ТС имел ввиду строку таблицы, а не NSString

Comment: высоту NSString я могу определить, но не могу определить высотку строки с другим контентом(видео, изображения)